# Instantiated Enemies Following the Player Overlap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So for my top down RPG, there are enemies in the overworld that will chase you if you get too close. (Like most turn-based RPGs nowadays.) The way it works is that the enemy spawner instantiates enemies at a random position at the start of the scene. That's not the problem, but the problem is the enemy overworld script itself.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyOverworld : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Details")]
    public BattleChar[] enemiesInArea;
    public int musicToPlay;
    public int maxAmountOfEnemies;
    public bool cannotFlee;
    public bool boss;

    [Header("Overworld Details")]
    public float speed;
    Vector3 dirToPlayer;
    public bool chase = false;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!GameManager.instance.battleActive && chase)
        {
            dirToPlayer = (CameraController.instance.target.position - transform.position).normalized;

            if (dirToPlayer.magnitude > 0)
            {
                transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, CameraController.instance.target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (!chase)
        {
            chase = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (chase)
        {
            float wait = 1;

            while (wait > 0)
            {
                wait -= Time.deltaTime;
            }

            chase = false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator StartBattleCo()
    {
        List<string> enemies = new();

        UIFade.instance.FadeToBlack();
        GameManager.instance.battleActive = true;
        int amount = 1;

        if (!boss)
        {
            amount = Random.Range(1, maxAmountOfEnemies);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            int enemy = Random.Range(0, enemiesInArea.Length);

            if (enemiesInArea[enemy].rareEnemy)
            {
                int chance = Random.Range(0, enemiesInArea[enemy].rarity * 10);

                if (chance <= enemiesInArea[enemy].rarity)
                {
                    enemies.Add(enemiesInArea[enemy].charName);
                }

                else
                {
                    i = i--;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                enemies.Add(enemiesInArea[enemy].charName);
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);

        BattleManager.instance.BattleStart(enemies.ToArray(), cannotFlee, boss, musicToPlay);

        UIFade.instance.FadeFromBlack();
        enemies.Clear();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

When the enemy chases the player, they'll often overlap one another, even though they both have capsule colliders (non-trigger) and rigidbodies on them.

I've tried different methods like translating the position instead of using MoveTowards, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as any physics is involved you do not want to move your object via

```
transform.position = ...
```

as this overrules the physics engine and directly teleports the objects without taking any collisions etc into account.

Instead rather use [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D m_Rigigbody;

...

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    ...

    m_Rigigbody.MovePosition(Vector2.MoveTowards(m_Rigigbody.position, CameraController.instance.target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime));

    ...
}
```

which will take collisions into account.

Comment: That didn't work. They are still overlapping each other and I used the exact same code in your snippet. Does anything have to do with the type of rigidbody?

Comment: Do they all have Collider2D? Are they all now only moved via the Rigidbody or is something still being moved using transform or other means?